# DocuSign API Set Signer Language Not Working for First Signer

Tags: docusignapi

In my tests so far when creating and sending an envelope using the DocuSign API v2.1 it is not respecting the setting for the supportedLanguage for the first signer, but does for the 2nd signer.

Here's the JSON for Signers array that I'm using:

```
"signers" : 
    [
        {
            "email" : "test@acme.com",
            "emailNotification" : 
            {
                "emailBody" : "",
                "emailSubject" : "Please Sign the Agreement",
                "supportedLanguage" : "de"
            },
            "name" : "Elisabeth Kiefer",
            "recipientId" : "1",
            "routingOrder" : "1",
            "tabs" : 
            {
                "dateSignedTabs" : 
                [
                    {
                        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent" : false,
                        "anchorString" : "/DateSigned1/",
                        "anchorUnits" : "pixels",
                        "anchorXOffset" : "0",
                        "anchorYOffset" : "0",
                        "documentId" : "1",
                        "locked" : "false",
                        "name" : "Date Signed",
                        "pageNumber" : "1",
                        "tabLabel" : "Data Signed",
                        "value" : ""
                    }
                ],
                "fullNameTabs" : 
                [
                    {
                        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent" : false,
                        "anchorString" : "/SigName1/",
                        "anchorUnits" : "pixels",
                        "anchorXOffset" : "0",
                        "anchorYOffset" : "0",
                        "documentId" : "1",
                        "locked" : "false",
                        "name" : "Name",
                        "pageNumber" : "1",
                        "tabLabel" : "Name",
                        "value" : ""
                    }
                ],
                "signHereTabs" : 
                [
                    {
                        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent" : false,
                        "anchorString" : "/Signature1/",
                        "anchorUnits" : "pixels",
                        "anchorXOffset" : "0",
                        "anchorYOffset" : "0",
                        "documentId" : "1",
                        "locked" : "false",
                        "name" : "Sign Here",
                        "pageNumber" : "1",
                        "tabLabel" : "Signature",
                        "value" : ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "email" : "test2@random.com",
            "emailNotification" : 
            {
                "emailBody" : "",
                "emailSubject" : "Please Sign the Agreement",
                "supportedLanguage" : "es"
            },
            "name" : "Fabio Gallego",
            "recipientId" : "2",
            "routingOrder" : "1",
            "tabs" : 
            {
                "dateSignedTabs" : 
                [
                    {
                        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent" : false,
                        "anchorString" : "/DateSigned2/",
                        "anchorUnits" : "pixels",
                        "anchorXOffset" : "0",
                        "anchorYOffset" : "0",
                        "documentId" : "1",
                        "locked" : "false",
                        "name" : "Date Signed",
                        "pageNumber" : "1",
                        "tabLabel" : "Data Signed",
                        "value" : ""
                    }
                ],
                "fullNameTabs" : 
                [
                    {
                        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent" : false,
                        "anchorString" : "/SigName2/",
                        "anchorUnits" : "pixels",
                        "anchorXOffset" : "0",
                        "anchorYOffset" : "0",
                        "documentId" : "1",
                        "locked" : "false",
                        "name" : "Name",
                        "pageNumber" : "1",
                        "tabLabel" : "Name",
                        "value" : ""
                    }
                ],
                "signHereTabs" : 
                [
                    {
                        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent" : false,
                        "anchorString" : "/Signature2/",
                        "anchorUnits" : "pixels",
                        "anchorXOffset" : "0",
                        "anchorYOffset" : "0",
                        "documentId" : "1",
                        "locked" : "false",
                        "name" : "Sign Here",
                        "pageNumber" : "1",
                        "tabLabel" : "Signature",
                        "value" : ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
```

You can see that the first signer's supportedLanguage is set to "de" and the second signer is set to "es". When I receive the emails for these and view the document only the second signer has the language set for the website and email. The first signer has everything in English and not German as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language setting is superseded by the user's selected lang that comes from the account.
So, you may want to change the email address to both to some random/unused emails that you know for sure are not part of any account user and check again.
There's no way for you to force the languages of the enduser, they can always overwrite your selection.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of this - much appreciated. Tested with a different email and works as expected.